# Can we use hybridised orbitals in Tight-Binding Method for calculation energy dispersion?

Tags: condensed-matter, atomic-physics, orbitals, dispersion, tight-binding

I am working on a model of a Fe square planar complex with nitrogen and oxygen given below is a monomer of that polymer. While constructing the hamiltonian matrix of this monomer I'm confused as to if I should take the orbitals of Nitrogen and Oxygen as normal atomic orbitals or hybridised orbitals? I tried to search up about it but couldn't find any method that used hybridized orbitals

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you build an hamiltonian using basis set of hybrid orbitals, it does not make sense because hybrid orbitals are supposed to represent only a geometrical picture of the ground state not a basis function with well-known coefficients. As the orbitals do not have the same symmetry in a coumpound, and the symmetry group commutes approximately with the hamiltonian, none the eigenvectors will be an hybrid orbital.

The TB approximation is based on a LCAO basis-set that should contain normal orbitals $\phi_i$, giving  $\psi = \sum_i c_i \phi_i$ , $c_i$ are unknown and are to be determined. You can get the conventional expression  by applying the Bloch's theorem. Nevertheless, the $\psi$s are not hybrid orbitals, hybrid orbitals could be a combination of several eigenvectors. You definitely need to use $2s$ and $2p$ orbitals for Oxygen and Nitrogen to build your hamiltonian.

Comment: the hybridised orbitals also change their energies compared to atomic orbitals which might affect the overall interaction, moreover after I've constructed the $\tilde{H}$ matrix in k-space I am using $\tilde{H}_k-\epsilon_k S_k|=0$ for getting bands where I have to consider the overlap integral which changes with the geometry. Is that not affected by the hybrid orbitals?

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra You have to define what you called hybrid orbitals in the chemistry sense or an arbritary mix of $s-$ and $p-$ like orbitals. Anyway, your choice of basis-set can affect your results, especially if your TB parameters are issued from another method.

Comment: in the sense of chemical hybrid orbitals that is here sp2 and sp3. Can I take those as the basis set while constructing the Hamiltonian matrix?

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra Of course not as I said, you can't. And what will be the hybridization of iron $sp^2$ or $sp^3$ 
 by using this basis-set ? You ought to use normal orbitals, you groundstate will converge will converge to the geometry of what you call hybridized orbitals.

Comment: What do you mean by converge? We don't exactly do any convergence in this TBA right?

Comment: @HarshdeepChhabra You know perfectly that TBA is semi-empirical and the hopping parameters are obtained by a fit with an ab initio band structure. The result of this fit  should match the ab initio result so that your TB basis set gives a geometry corresponding to an ab initio calculation : hybridized orbitals. That was what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Hybridized orbitals(Ashcroft&Mermin Solid state physics chapter 10) but so that you have one orbital per monomer (which would fit in the unit cell of the Bravais lattice). However considering atomic orbitals would be easier, and you need to mix them i.e. your trial function would be of the form $$\sum_R e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{R}}[a^k_{Fe}\Phi_{Fe}(r)+a^k_{O1}\Phi_{O}(r-r_{O1})+a^k_{O2}\Phi_{O}(r-r_{O2})+\cdots]$$ Where $\Phi_{Fe(O)}$ is the most relevant Iron(oxygen) atomic orbital You will find energies and the coefficients $a^k$ by solving the eigen equation using this wavefuntion, which would be  equivalent to using hybridized orbitals (LCAO type) in some sense. Some other examples following such a procedure would be solving the tight binding model for graphene [https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~phys123B/w2015/pdf_CoursGraphene2008.pdf](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Ephys123B/w2015/pdf_CoursGraphene2008.pdf)

and bi-layer graphene https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.6953.pdf

I hope this helps.[image]